# xslt 1.0. I need to select few nodes and exclude others in the following expression

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

I need to include all 01 recordCode nodes only from E0 sibling but need to ignore the ones under E2 and E3 and i am getting all of 01 followed by E0 using the code below. Not sure how to create the key above that would just result in a node with all 01s that follow only E0.
Here is my current xslt.

```
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <!-- Generate keys for Approver, VAT, and Narrative Arrays -->
    <xsl:key name="kApproverDetailArray" match="faRecord[recordCode='01']" use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::faRecord[recordCode='E0'][1])" />
    <xsl:key name="kVATDetailArray" match="faRecord[recordCode='02']" use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::faRecord[recordCode='E0'][1])" />
    <xsl:key name="kNarrativeArray" match="faRecord[recordCode='03']" use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::faRecord[recordCode='E0'][1])" />
    <xsl:key name="kItemWorkCodeNarrativeArray" match="faRecord[recordCode='01']" use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::faRecord[recordCode='E2'][1])" />
    <xsl:key name="kOrderRecordApproverArray" match="faRecord[recordCode='01']" use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::faRecord[recordCode='E3'][1])" />

    <xsl:template match="InvoiceDisplayRequest">
        <MCSResponse>
            <InvoiceDisplayResponse>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="*/faRecord[recordCode='E0']" mode="InvoiceDisplayResponse" />
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="facXML/faRecord[recordCode='E1']" mode="InvoiceDisplayResponse" />
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="facXML/faRecord[recordCode='E3']" mode="InvoiceDisplayResponse" />
                    <xsl:apply-templates select="facXML/faRecord[recordCode='E2']" mode="InvoiceDisplayResponse" />
            </InvoiceDisplayResponse>
        </MCSResponse>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="faRecord[recordCode='E0']" mode="InvoiceDisplayResponse">
        <InvoiceDisplayDetail>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="item" mode="InvoiceDisplayDetail" />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="key('kApproverDetailArray', generate-id())" mode="InvoiceDisplayResponse" />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="key('kVATDetailArray', generate-id())" mode="InvoiceDisplayResponse"/>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="key('kNarrativeArray', generate-id())" mode="InvoiceDisplayResponse"/>
        </InvoiceDisplayDetail>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- InvoiceDisplayDetail fields  -->   
    <xsl:template match="item[itemMapCode='1']" mode="InvoiceDisplayDetail">
        <LogNumber>
            <xsl:value-of select="./itemValue" />
        </LogNumber>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="item[itemMapCode='2']" mode="InvoiceDisplayDetail">
        <LogAddedDate>
            <xsl:value-of select="./itemValue" />
        </LogAddedDate>
    </xsl:template>


    <!-- Approver Array fields  -->
    <xsl:template match="faRecord[recordCode='01']" mode="InvoiceDisplayResponse">
        <ApproverArray> 
            <xsl:apply-templates select="item" mode="ApproverArray" />
        </ApproverArray> 
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- VAT Array fields  -->
    <xsl:template match="faRecord[recordCode='02']" mode="InvoiceDisplayResponse">
        <VATDetailArray> 
            <xsl:apply-templates select="item" mode="VATDetailArray" />
        </VATDetailArray> 
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="item[itemMapCode='1']" mode="VATDetailArray">
        <VATSequence>
            <xsl:value-of select="./itemValue" />
        </VATSequence>
    </xsl:template>


    <!-- Narrative Array fields  -->
    <xsl:template match="faRecord[recordCode='03']" mode="InvoiceDisplayResponse">
        <NarrativeArray> 
            <xsl:apply-templates select="item" mode="NarrativeArray" />
        </NarrativeArray> 
    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template match="item[itemMapCode='1']" mode="NarrativeArray">
        <Narrative>
            <xsl:value-of select="./itemValue" />
        </Narrative>
    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template match="faRecord[recordCode='E1']" mode="InvoiceDisplayResponse">
        <ItemRecord>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="item" mode="InvoiceItemRecord" />
        </ItemRecord>
    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template match="faRecord[recordCode='E2']" mode="InvoiceDisplayResponse">
        <ItemWorkCodeRecord>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="item" mode="InvoiceItemWorkCodeRecord" />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="key('kItemWorkCodeNarrativeArray', generate-id())" mode="InvoiceItemWorkCodeRecord"/>
        </ItemWorkCodeRecord>
    </xsl:template>
    <!-- Invoice Item WorkCode (E2 response) Narrative Array fields  -->
    <xsl:template match="faRecord[recordCode='01']" mode="InvoiceItemWorkCodeRecord">
        <NarrativeArray> 
            <xsl:apply-templates select="item" mode="ItemWorkCodeNarrativeArray" />
        </NarrativeArray> 
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="item[itemMapCode='1']" mode="ItemWorkCodeNarrativeArray">
        <Narrative>
            <xsl:value-of select="./itemValue" />
        </Narrative>
    </xsl:template>


    <xsl:template match="faRecord[recordCode='E3']" mode="InvoiceDisplayResponse">
        <OrderRecord>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="item" mode="OrderArray" />
            <xsl:apply-templates select="key('kOrderRecordApproverArray', generate-id())" mode="InvoiceOrderRecord" />
        </OrderRecord>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Invoice order record (E3 response) Approver Array fields  -->
    <xsl:template match="faRecord[recordCode='01']" mode="InvoiceOrderRecord">
        <ApproverArray> 
            <xsl:apply-templates select="item" mode="ApproverArray" />
        </ApproverArray> 
    </xsl:template>



    <!--  Ignore any other fields -->
    <xsl:template match="*" mode="InvoiceDisplayDetail"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Here is my source xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<InvoiceDisplayRequest>
    <facXML>
        <faRecord>
            <recordCode>E0</recordCode>
            <item>
                <itemMapCode>1</itemMapCode>
                <itemValue>B000011</itemValue>
            </item>
        </faRecord>
        <faRecord>
            <recordCode>01</recordCode>
            <item>
                <itemMapCode>1</itemMapCode>
                <itemValue>1</itemValue>
            </item>
            <item>
                <itemMapCode>2</itemMapCode>
                <itemValue>2000</itemValue>
            </item>
        </faRecord>
        <faRecord>
            <recordCode>01</recordCode>
            <item>
                <itemMapCode>1</itemMapCode>
                <itemValue>1</itemValue>
            </item>
            <item>
                <itemMapCode>2</itemMapCode>
                <itemValue>2000</itemValue>
            </item>
        </faRecord>
        <faRecord>
            <recordCode>E0</recordCode>
            <item>
                <itemMapCode>41</itemMapCode>
                <itemValue>N</itemValue>
            </item>
        </faRecord>
        <faRecord>
            <recordCode>02</recordCode>
            <item>
                <itemMapCode>1</itemMapCode>
                <itemValue>1</itemValue>
            </item>
            <item>
                <itemMapCode>2</itemMapCode>
                <itemValue>S</itemValue>
            </item>
            <item>
                <itemMapCode>3</itemMapCode>
                <itemValue>STRD</itemValue>
            </item>
            <item>
                <itemMapCode>4</itemMapCode>
                <itemValue>3080</itemValue>
            </item>
            <item>
                <itemMapCode>5</itemMapCode>
                <itemValue>0</itemValue>
            </item>
        </faRecord>
        <faRecord>
            <recordCode>03</recordCode>
            <item>
                <itemMapCode>1</itemMapCode>
                <itemValue>narrative at invoice level here. Invoice log will only allow me to input 100 characters I believe. E</itemValue>
            </item>
        </faRecord>
        <faRecord>
            <recordCode>E1</recordCode>
            <item>
                <itemMapCode>1</itemMapCode>
                <itemValue>1</itemValue>
            </item>
            <item>
                <itemMapCode>2</itemMapCode>
                <itemValue>TFR</itemValue>
            </item>
        </faRecord>
        <faRecord>
            <recordCode>E2</recordCode>
            <item>
                <itemMapCode>1</itemMapCode>
                <itemValue>1</itemValue>
            </item>
            <item>
                <itemMapCode>2</itemMapCode>
                <itemValue>1</itemValue>
            </item>
            <item>
                <itemMapCode>3</itemMapCode>
                <itemValue>02</itemValue>
            </item>
        </faRecord>
        <faRecord>
            <recordCode>01</recordCode>
            <item>
                <itemMapCode>1</itemMapCode>
                <itemValue>12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890</itemValue>
            </item>
        </faRecord>
        <faRecord>
            <recordCode>01</recordCode>
            <item>
                <itemMapCode>1</itemMapCode>
                <itemValue>12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890</itemValue>
            </item>
        </faRecord>
        <faRecord>
            <recordCode>01</recordCode>
            <item>
                <itemMapCode>1</itemMapCode>
                <itemValue>12345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789012345678901234567890</itemValue>
            </item>
        </faRecord>
        <faRecord>
            <recordCode>E2</recordCode>
            <item>
                <itemMapCode>1</itemMapCode>
                <itemValue>1</itemValue>
            </item>
            <item>
                <itemMapCode>2</itemMapCode>
                <itemValue>2</itemValue>
            </item>
            <item>
                <itemMapCode>3</itemMapCode>
                <itemValue>AC</itemValue>
            </item>
            <item>
                <itemMapCode>4</itemMapCode>
                <itemValue>Actor</itemValue>
            </item>
            <item>
                <itemMapCode>5</itemMapCode>
                <itemValue>5400</itemValue>
            </item>
            <item>
                <itemMapCode>6</itemMapCode>
                <itemValue>0</itemValue>
            </item>
            <item>
                <itemMapCode>7</itemMapCode>
                <itemValue>1</itemValue>
            </item>
            <item>
                <itemMapCode>8</itemMapCode>
                <itemValue>1080</itemValue>
            </item>
            <item>
                <itemMapCode>9</itemMapCode>
                <itemValue>0</itemValue>
            </item>
        </faRecord>
        <faRecord>
            <recordCode>01</recordCode>
            <item>
                <itemMapCode>1</itemMapCode>
                <itemValue>narrative at gird level here</itemValue>
            </item>
        </faRecord>
    </facXML>
</InvoiceDisplayRequest>
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and provide a [mcve] demonstrating your problem.  Formatting your desired output, making it be well-formed, and removing the spurious `-` characters would be nice too.

Comment: I have edited and removed the dashes from xml but to provide the entire code would be a lot of code and not sure if anyone would be able to look at it.

Comment: Nobody said anything about the *entire* code.  Please provide a [mcve] (note ***Minimal***).  Failure to do so results in wasted time on your and our ends.   @hr_117 would have had an answer for you in a fraction of the time it took him to guess and miss in his (now deleted) answer, for example.

Comment: Ok edited again. Not sure if this is enough to explain the problem. This code may not work without the entire xsl.

Comment: It would be rely easier if you could provide a complete xslt showing the problem, but this should not be your entire production xslt. Only a refused working on with may be 30 lines of code.

Comment: ***After way too many ignored requests, you still haven't created a [mcve]***.   You're wasting everyone's time.  Voting to close.

Comment: I am sorry @kjhughes. This is my first post here and i am very new to xslt. I now do understand that i needed to provide more parts of the xslt that could have reproduced this problem. I thought the main issue was the code that i provided and was enough to describe the problem. I am new to xslt and wasn't sure what else i could provide that can reproduce the problem. I will certainly do that next time i post a question and if i do have something that i have coded.

Comment: @R.Gup, no problem, but why don't you click the ***[edit]*** link, add a **[mcve]** to this question right now, and I'll remove any comments made obsolete by your updates?  Thanks.

Comment: It's done. I have added the xslt that can be used to recreate the original issue.

Answer (score 1):

Only  guessing. But basically you should change the key as following:
(update with key fix)

```
<xsl:key name="kApproverDetailArray" match="faRecord[recordCode='01']"
         use="generate-id(
              preceding-sibling::faRecord[recordCode='E0' or recordCode='E2'][1])" />
```

With that you can loop over all `"faRecord[recordCode='01']` following `faRecord[recordCode='E0' ]`:

```
 <xsl:template match="facXML">
    <xsl:for-each select="faRecord[recordCode='E0' ]">
      <xsl:for-each select="key('kApproverDetailArray', generate-id())  ">
         <!-- do something -->
      </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: This code will group all the 01 that follows E0 and E2. I only need to group 01 that follows E0. My current code groups all 01s which is what i am trying to avoid.  Here is what i currently have and your key is giving me the same results. <xsl:key name="kApproverDetailArray" match="faRecord[recordCode='01']" use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::faRecord[recordCode='E0'][1])" />

Comment: I need something like this but i get error not sure what the correct syntax is for the AND operator <xsl:key name="kApproverDetailArray" match="faRecord[recordCode='01']" use="generate-id((preceding-sibling::faRecord[recordCode ='E0'] and
                       preceding-sibling::faRecord[recordCode !='E2'])[1] )" />

Comment: @R.Gup  No it groups all 01 foll0wing the E0  or E2. Therefor the key (generated-id) for E0 holds only the 01 which following the E0. The 01 folloing the E2 have the generated-id from the E2, Trey it,

Comment: Sorry, I just tried it and it's still grouping all 01 following E0 and E2 under E0. Here is how i access it. <xsl:template match="faRecord[recordCode='E0']" mode="InvoiceDisplayResponse">
     <xsl:apply-templates select="key('kApproverDetailArray', generate-id())" mode="InvoiceDisplayResponse" />
 </xsl:template>

Comment: A gallant guess (+1), but we shouldn't have to guess.  OP refuses to post a [mcve], so rather than encourage a long, painful string of explanatory comments, this question should simply be closed.

Comment: Thank you. The updated key works. What's the difference between "|" and "or".